# VBA: Recordset.Fields "Object doesn't support this property"

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, ado, adodb

I am trying to iterate through the fields on each recordset and have their values added to my Excel 2007 worksheet.

I have the following code, but I am getting "Object doesn't support this property" whenever it reaches "***For Each x In..***"
Am I missing something ? Do I need to add additional references in VBA to use .Fields? I am currently using **Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.0 Library** on my references. The SQL queries an Oracle Database, but I don't suppose that matters in this error.

```
Set recSet = newConn.getOpenIncidents("exampleworkgroup")
Set Path = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Incidents")
iRow = 2

With Path
    iCol = 1
    For Each x In recSet.Fields
        .Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = x.Value  'Customer Name
        iCol = iCol + 1
    Next
End With
```

And this is the code for the function in my class

```
Public Function getOpenIncidents(ByVal wrkgp As String)
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim SQL As String

    SQL = "SELECT intbl.cust_ky, intbl.incid_id, intbl.OPEN_TS, intbl.CLOSE_TS, wrkgptbl.wrkgp_id, intbl.incid_ttl_dn " _
        & "FROM (MAIN.testtable intbl INNER JOIN MAIN.wrkgrp wrkgptbl ON intbl.curr_wrkgp_ky=wrkgptbl.wrkgp_ky) " _
        & "WHERE wrkgptbl.wrkgp_id='" & wrkgp & "'"

    rs.Open SQL, con, adOpenKeyset
    rs.MoveFirst
    getOpenIncidents = rs

End Function
```

Comment: What happens if you try `recSet.Fields.Count` before your For Each?

Comment: is `recSet` actually a recordset? Your `GetOpenIncidents()` function returns a Variant and there is no `Set` in the function either.

Comment: @creamyegg I did not declare recSet as a recordset. But shouldn't it be one after getting the variant from the function ? I added watch on recSet, and I was able to see 6 items in it. How can I iterate those 6 items ?

Comment: @p.campbell I tried. got the same error "Object doesn't support this property or method" :((

Comment: I got "Object doesn't support this property or method" for recSet.Close too. Starting to wonder if I am using the right reference or whether I need to add additional references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've spotted it! `recSet` is actually of type Fields. as such there is no such `.Fields` property as `.Fields` is a property of a Recordset Object.

The fix should be:

```
For Each x In recSet
```

Or change the `getOpenIncidents()` method to return a RecordSet (including changing the return line to `Set getOpenIncidents  = rs`).